# Logarithmic Axis on Visiblox

Tags: logarithm, visiblox

I'm having trouble setting the range of an axis so that the minimum is below 1. I understand that no value less than 0 can be plotted by I don't understand why values below 1 cannot be viewed unless I can pan to them.
Is there any reason for this? Or a way of resolving it?

Comment: Can you post some code?  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure that code would help, I mean if you set the range for a visiblox control to have a minimum of less than 1 it ignores it. Are you saying that it works for you?

Comment: After some research, it appears this is as designed.  The minimum value is 1.  I can manually set the range, but it still doesn't draw the points below 1.  And when points exist above 1, it automatically defaults the minimum to 1 anyway.  I would suggest contacting someone at Visiblox.  You can try wreilly at visiblox dot com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may be as designed, you could still achieve the affect you're looking for by scaling your data up into the valid range for the logarithmic axis.  Then you could override the label function to set the labels you want.  It's hacky, but it might work for your needs.

```
class MyLogarithmicAxis : LogarithmicAxis
{
    protected override string GetFormattedDataValueInternal(double dataValue, string formatString)
    {
        if (dataValue == 1)
        {
            dataValue = .1;
        }
        if (dataValue == 100)
        {
            dataValue = 10;
        }
        if (dataValue == 1000)
        {
            dataValue = 100;
        }

        return base.GetFormattedDataValueInternal(dataValue, formatString);
    }
}
```