# Visiblox log axis does not show grid lines and values when zoomed

Tags: charts, zooming, visiblox

I have a software that displays charts using Visiblox. 
The user can change the style of any of the axes from linear to logarithmic. And I have a small problem:
When zoomed the linear chart will display grid lines on the graph and values on the axis, as can be seen in the following two pictures: [image: linear chart unzoomed]

[image: linear chart zoomed]

The problem is that when switched to logarithmic mode the chart no linger displays the reference numbers or grid lines when zoomed:
[image: log chart unzoomed]
[image: log chart zoomed]

So our users are now complaining they have no reference to analyze the curves.
We don't do any special configuration to linear axes opposed to log ones here's the code:

for linear axes:

```
  this.CalibrationChartXAxis = new LinearAxis();
  this.CalibrationChartYAxis = new LinearAxis();
```

for log axes:

```
this.CalibrationChartXAxis = new LogarithmicAxis();
this.CalibrationChartYAxis = new LogarithmicAxis();
```

adding the ranges:

```
this.CalibrationChartXAxis.Range = new DoubleRange(minX, maxX);
this.CalibrationChartYAxis.Range = new DoubleRange(minY, maxY);
```

and of course binding them to the view:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <charts:Chart  x:Name="PlotChart" Behaviour="{Binding Path=CalibrationCurveChartViewModel.PlotChartBehavior}"
              XAxis="{Binding Path=CalibrationCurveChartViewModel.CalibrationChartXAxis}" 
              YAxis="{Binding Path=CalibrationCurveChartViewModel.CalibrationChartYAxis}" 
                      Background="Transparent" LegendVisibility="Collapsed" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
        <charts:Chart.Series>
         ...
        </charts:Chart.Series>
      </charts:Chart>
   </Grid>
```

I have no idea why the two axes types behave differently.
I've tried turning AutoScaleToVisibleData on and off, or setting ShowMinorTicks, but that seems to do nothing. 
I'm at a loss about what to do.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar before.  Not sure if this is related, but you can check out this post for a possible workaround.

[Logarithmic Axis on Visiblox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910366/logarithmic-axis-on-visiblox/23964215#23964215)

Comment: thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.
the solution posted there allows me to change the labels, while my labels are missing altogether.

Comment: @memoryofadream The labels are missing because the data is not in the visible range.  The workaround is to scale the data up by 10 into the visible range.  Then to modify the labels at that point.  It's hacky, but it works for the other case.

Comment: that would mean I have implement my own scrolling. To allow users to scroll in or out only by factors of 10 at a time. 

Should work, but I hope to find a simpler way to do it?